# Is it possible to union a layer of polygon in geopandas without selecting a second layer?

Tags: python, geopandas

I need to perform a union operation inside a single layer. In Qgis there is an option not to select the second layer, but I can't figure out how to do it in geopandas?

Can you write the code of this operation?
Something like this: `union = gpd.overlay(zone, how='union')`

Comment: Something like `zone.unary_union` or `zone.geometry.unary_union`, maybe? I'm not totally sure what the question is asking for - I don't have much Qgis experience. Maybe you could post an example geodataframe and show how you're looking for it to be transformed?

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/460405/how-to-self-union-multipolygon-layer-a-geodataframe here is an example